# qt creator code to start process

Tags: qt-creator

I want to start process( I mean open an executable file ) from from inside my qt creator project, for example in c# we use : 
system.diagonistic.procces.start(file/path);
What is the corresponding in qt creator ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation of QProcess?